# Custom MessageConverter with Spring JmsMessagingTemplate is not working as I expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-messaging

I'm trying to attach a custom message converter that implements `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter`, to a `JmsMessagingTemplate`.

I've read somewhere that we can attach the message converter to a `MessagingMessageConverter` by calling `setPayloadConverter`, and then attach that messaging message converter to the `JmsMessagingTemplate` via `setJmsMessageConverter`. After that, I call `convertAndSend`, but I notice that it doesn't convert the payload.

When I debugged the code, I notice that setting Jms Message Converter doesn't set the `converter` instance variable in the `JmsMessagingTemplate`. So when the `convertAndSend` method calls `doConvert` and tries to `getConverter`, it is getting the default simple message converter and not my custom one.

My question is, can I use an implementation of `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter` with a `JmsMessagingTemplate`? Or do I need to use an implementation of `org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter`?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE, and Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE. The code is below.

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MessagingEncryptionPocConfig {
    /**
     * Listener ActiveMQ Connection Factory
     */
    @Bean(name="listenerActiveMqConnectionFactory")
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory listenerActiveMqConnectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61616");
    }

    /**
     * Producer ActiveMQ Connection Factory
     */
    @Bean(name="producerActiveMqConnectionFactory")
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory producerActiveMqConnectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61616");
    }   

    /**
     * Caching Connection Factory
     */
    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(@Qualifier("producerActiveMqConnectionFactory") ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory) {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMqConnectionFactory);
    }

    /**
     * JMS Listener Container Factory
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("listenerActiveMqConnectionFactory") ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessagingMessageConverter messageConverter) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Jms Queue Template
     */
    @Bean(name="queueTemplate")
    public JmsMessagingTemplate queueTemplate(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory, MessageConverter messagingMessageConverter) {
        JmsMessagingTemplate queueTemplate = new JmsMessagingTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
        queueTemplate.setJmsMessageConverter(messagingMessageConverter);
        return queueTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter encryptionDecryptionMessagingConverter(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller) {
        MessageConverter encryptionDecryptionMessagingConverter = new EncryptionDecryptionMessagingConverter(jaxb2Marshaller);
        MessagingMessageConverter messageConverter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setPayloadConverter(encryptionDecryptionMessagingConverter);
        return messageConverter;
    }

    /**
     * Jaxb marshaller
     */
    @Bean(name="producerJaxb2Marshaller")
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.schema");
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }
}
```

**MessageProducer Class**

```
@Component 
public class MessageProducer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("queueTemplate")
    private JmsMessagingTemplate queueTemplate;

    public void publishMsg(Transaction trx, Map<String,Object> jmsHeaders, MessagePostProcessor postProcessor) {
        LOG.info("Sending Message. Payload={} Headers={}",trx,jmsHeaders);
        queueTemplate.convertAndSend("queue.source", trx, jmsHeaders, postProcessor);
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class WebsMessagingEncryptionPocApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MessageProducer producer;

    @Autowired
    private MessageListener messageListener;    

    /**
     * Ensure that a message is sent, and received.
     */
    @Test
    public void testProducer() throws Exception{
        //ARRANGE
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        messageListener.setCountDownLatch(latch);
        Transaction trx = new Transaction();
        trx.setCustomerAccountID(new BigInteger("111111"));
        Map<String,Object> jmsHeaders = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        jmsHeaders.put("tid", "1234563423");
        MessagePostProcessor encryptPostProcessor = new EncryptMessagePostProcessor();
        //ACT
        producer.publishMsg(trx, jmsHeaders, encryptPostProcessor);
        latch.await();
        //ASSERT - assertion done in the consumer       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `converter` field is used to convert your input params to a spring-messaging `Message<?>`.

The JMS converter is used later (in `MessagingMessageCreator`) to then create a JMS `Message` from the messaging `Message<?>`.

Comment: Thanks Gary! If I would like to convert something before the `MessagePostProcessor` is executed, then I should populate the `converter` field instead, correct?

Comment: That is correct; or you can simply use a `JmsTemplate` instead and set the headers in the MPP instead of passing them into the method - this would avoid the double conversion.